# Git describe: print only tag and commit ahead and not commit-id

Tags: git

the `git describe` command returns this `2.1.0-4-gfca019a`
where

- `2.1.0`: is the tag
- `4`: means 4 commits ahead
- `gfca019a` is the commit hash (part of it)

is it possible to return only the first 2 values, that's `2.1.0-4`?

Do i have to do fancy command? (if so, what?)
or does git give this opportunity

Comment: Seems to not be possible. `--abbrev=0` strips both the commit hash an the commit-ahead number.

Comment: Why do you want the ambiguity?

Comment: i need that because i use the git describe for the creation of docker images, only from develop branch.
doing so i need to copy and paste the full describe when deploying. while if it's short i could just remember that .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't found a builtin way to do this with `git describe` directly, but you can use `sed` or similar tools to strip off the trailing parts:

```
git describe --tags --long | sed 's/-g[[:xdigit:]]*$//'
```

Note that there can be any number of commits that are N commits ahead of a given tag, so the description without the commit hash is ambiguous and no longer uniquely identifies a single commit.

Comment: thanks, can you briefly explain the text within the sed command?

Comment: @EsseTi It matches the last part of the describe output and replaces it with nothing/empty string. https://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618/112968

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

`git describe --tags --abbrev=0`

Comment: This strips the "commit ahead" count as well